# How can I use a new main.html for a component in Voltrb?

Tags: ruby, view, voltrb

I added a component for an admin and a guest section to my volt app and now I need a new main.html to customize the main template for these sections.
Is there a way to use a new main.html ore to load the views in a template file for a component?

Thank you for help and sorry if I miss something in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now app/main/views/main.html is always loaded first. You can change it around so it just renders some other layout.  On my short term todo list is to add support for other "root components", which you would be able to setup from your admin component.  Haven't gotten that out the door yet though :-(